# C++ open url in new window with ShellExecute

Tags: c++

As you can tell from the title i'm looking for a way to open a url in a new window not in pre existing window. I've looked around for a little bit and can't find anything and was just wondering if anyone knew how to. I'm thinking it'll look something like this:

```cpp
        if (hwnd == NULL) {
            ShellExecute(hwnd, L"open", L"brave", L"about:blank", 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            hwnd = GetActiveWindow();
        }
```

obliviously the hwnd is null so that won't work. Also if you haven't figured it out i'm on windows.

Comment: Check the return value of [`ShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) for hints. While on that page, see also what `SW_HIDE` means.

Comment: How would I go about making a HINSTANCE that would open a link in a new tab?

Comment: The HINSTANCE is what ShellExecute returns. So (fill in the blanks): `HINSTANCE hInst = ShellExecute(...); if((int)hInst <= 32) { /* check the error code */ } `.

Comment: Yes that defiantly is helpful with debugging but how would I apply that to Opening a link in a new tab?

Comment: That's a matter of browser settings, or perhaps command line switches. The answer to that question does not lie with C++ or programming in general.

Comment: ok i needed to put a switch into the parameters to pass to the bowser ```ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"Brave", L"-new-window", 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);```